# Control C doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

In both gnome-terminal and terminator, press ctrl+c doesn't do ANYTHING. It doesn't kill processes, it doesn't cancel whatever's on the current line and start a new one, nothing. ctrl+shift+c works, so it isn't my keyboard. What's wrong?

EDIT: Pressing ctrl+c in a running process prints "^C", it just doesn't kill the process even if it's a process that is normally killed by a SIGINT, which makes me think that ctrl+c isn't sending a SIGINT.

EDIT 2: The output of `stty -a` is:

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

EDIT 3: It's working again. I have no idea why. I didn't remove or install anything other than xclip, I have no idea why this is now working.

EDIT 4: It's no longer working.

Comment: Check your shortcuts in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts as those take precedence over application-specific shortcuts.

Comment: Everything is fine. Nothing in the shortcuts, and ctrl+c works in every other application. I've edited my post with new info. EDIT: ctrl+v ctrl+c prints "^C" in the terminal, so it's definitely not my keyboard or an overridden keybinding.

Comment: Can you post the output of `stty -a`?

Comment: Added another edit. intr is `^C`, so I don't know why this wouldn't be working.

Comment: Are you using Bash? If so what's the output of `bind -P | grep '\C-c'`?

Comment: @kos meant to say `bind -P | grep '\\C-c'`.

Comment: It _could_ be something with the SIGINT signal handler not being set to its default. gnome-terminal used to have (and in 14.04 probably still has) such an issue with `Ctrl+Backslash` [SIGQUIT] (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748520), although I haven't seen this happeneng with `Ctrl+C` [SIGINT].

Comment: @kos I am, there is no output, but ctrl+c is now working again

Comment: It stopped working again. I have no idea why

Comment: If it's intermittent, then it's likely the keyboard. In fact, nothing else so far explained such behavior. Please try with another keyboard and see see if the issue persists.

Comment: Please follow the link in my previous comment, and check whether the way you start up gnome-terminal (as described there) makes any difference. (You should close all gnome-terminal windows, and then start up the first window in those various ways.) I still suspect something with the signal handlers. You should check /proc/PID/status and compare the SigBlk, SigIgn, SigCgt fields when Ctrl+C is working vs. when it's not (whereas PID refers to the process that should receive the Ctrl+C).

Comment: Also, what happens if from another terminal you execute `kill -INT PID`, using the PID of the process you'd like to abort with Ctrl+C?

Comment: @kos it works. pressing ctrl+c copies text, and will print "^C" when running a process in the terminal. It just must not be sending the interrupt. @egmont `kill -INT PID` kills firefox, so that works. Following your instructions, I launched terminator normally (instead of with Rofi) and it works perfectly. Guess that was the issue then. Sucks, I like Rofi. If you add an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @egmont probably didn't get notified since you can notify only one user at the time within one comment; egmont, could you write an answer to this?

Comment: @Kookerus As a vte/gnome-terminal developer, I'm not happy with this answer yet. I have no clue what's happening behind the scenes, what's the technical reason for Ctrl+C not working, and whether it's vte's or rofi's fault. Ideally you should file a bug against vte or against rofi (maybe both, cross linking each other).

Comment: @egmont Is the bug you linked not a VTE bug? I've meant to test this using a clean i3 configuration, but due to personal issues, I haven't really gotten a chance yet. EDIT: Same issue with a clean i3 config.

Comment: @Kookerus The bug I linked is a similar one, but wouldn't justify why Ctrl+C didn't work. What's your VTE version?

Comment: @egmont How do I find that?

Comment: @egmont It was an issue with rofi, the program I was using to run the terminal. I was running it in daemon mode, which apparently breaks things. Running rofi normally and using it to launch terminator (or another term) works just fine.

Comment: @Kookerus `echo $VTE_VERSION` to get the version. I'm not satisfied with the answer blaming rofi in daemon mode. VTE should take care that no matter how it's started, it works as expected.

Comment: @egmont I still had the same issue with xterm, a non-VTE terminal, as well as terminator. It's a confirmed bug with rofi. $VTE_VERSION 3409

Comment: Rofi bugreport: https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi/issues/366

Comment: @egmont Yeah, that was from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation here in the comments, the bug turned out to occur only if the terminal is started up from Rofi's daemon mode. Rofi blocks SIGINT and forgets to unblock it prior to launching the application. Terminal emulators don't unblock it either, except for VTE as of the (now brand new) version 0.44. Rofi has also fixed its behavior.